# How to share iPhone's hotspot connection both Laptop and RPi

Tags: wifi, connection, internet, hotspot

I went on a vacation and unfortunately I have no internet connection in here. I have only mobile data for internet connection so I have to use hotspot for both my laptop and RPi.

I am using RPi 2 Model B, so i don't have Wi-Fi on Rpi

Here is the things that I have tried:

1- I connected to hotspot with my Laptop.

2- After that I tried to share its connection to RPi but i didn't work.

3- I bridged the wireless and ETH connection and I set my RPi address on same network

At the end, I can connect my RPi but it don't have internet connection. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Plug your iPhone into your Pi via the charging cable. Turn on your hotspot. Your Pi should detect it as Ethernet, and your laptop should be able to connect as normal through Wireless.

Good luck,
Josh.